# what does this function do in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

what does this function in Haskel do ?

I don't understand the way the recursion works here

```
 f[]=[]
 f(x:xs)=x: [y|y <- f xs, x/=y]
```

Comment: Have you tried running it? What particular it of the recursion don't you understand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
f[]=[]
f(x:xs) = x : [y|y <- f xs, x/=y]
```

This function removes duplicates from a list. Here's how it works:

- Base case, the list is empty, so it returns the empty list.
- Otherwise you take the first element `x`, and assume (inductive hypothesis) that `f xs` gives you the list without duplicates. Now, the only thing you have to do is make sure that you don't insert `x` again. So, the list comprension means: take all the rest of the elements (which by inductive hypothesis are unique), but remove the `x`.

Does it feel right now?

ps. you can write the second clause also as:
`f(x:xs) = x : filter (/= x) (f xs)`

Comment: You can rewrite the whole definition as: `f = foldr (\x -> (x :) . filter (/= x)) []`

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that it eliminates any duplicate entries in the list.

Here's how it works:

`f[] = []` means that, when the input is an empty list, the output will be an empty list.
Then, `f(x:xs) = x: [y|y <- f xs, x/=y]` uses what's called a list comprehension. It takes the head of the input list, and then appends the list comprehension.

The list comprehension reads like this: "y such that y is in f(xs), and y doesn't equal x"

So it's the list of elements in f(xs) that don't equal the head element.

Comment: I run   f[1,2,3,4,12,3,1,2,1,4] and I got the list without the duplicates... but I didn't get the way it works..

Comment: No, you can't; that would just get you the list of elements where the very first element isn't repeated. So, f([1, 1, 2, 2]) would return [1, 2, 2].